# Can display: flex; be broken?

Tags: css, flexbox

On this snippet I have two sections.

The first one shows two columns (using display: flex;) and a header above it on one column. I have to use an intermediate tag (article in this case) to keep the "flex" on its place.

But I am wondering if there is a CSS property that I could assign for example on the second case, to the h2 element, (like h2:first-of-type or something) so the flex property only affects the div, and skips the h2, so the bottom section behaves like the first case.

Is there such a feature?

```css
.Flex {
  display: flex}

div {
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 50%;}

h2 {text-align: center;}
 
/* This is just for visual */
section {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Title on one full width Column</h2>
  <article class="Flex">
    <div>Column three</div>
    <div>Column four</div>
  </article>
</section>


<section class="Flex">
  <h2>Title on one Column</h2>
  <div>Column one</div>
  <div>Column two</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not possible, once it becomes a flex item it cannot be reset, however you might be able to adjust it visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.Flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

div {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 50%;}

h2 {text-align: center;}
 .Flex h2{
   width: 100%;
 }
/* This is just for visual */
section {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;}
```

```html
  <section>
<h2>Title on one full width Column</h2>
<article class="Flex">
  <div>Column three</div>
  <div>Column four</div>
</article>
  </section>


  <section class="Flex">
<h2>Title on one Column</h2>
<div>Column one</div>
<div>Column two</div>
  </section>
```